# Git with development and production environment

Tags: git

I am new to git and looking for the most efficient way to setup development and production environment with git.

I develop locally on some projects, say:

```
project1.local
project2.local
project3.local
```

When I am ready I push the changes to the server, where beta tester can work with it:

```
beta.project1.com
beta.project2.com
beta.project3.com
```

Only if betatest succeeds I would like to push the changes to production domain:

```
www.project1.com
www.project2.com
www.project3.com
```

I do understand how to connect project1.local and beta.project1.com.
However, I do not really understand how to setup the connection between beta.project1.com and www.project1.com to push tested features into production.

Is git right for me?

Answer (score 6):

Check "*[A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)*" to do more or less what you want.

In `git` you can have multiples repositories (`git remote --help`).  So, in production you can have the repositories pointing to `beta`, and pull the changes from there.  In beta, you can have both, `production` and `development` and pull changes from development and push them to `production`.   For each case, you should handle branches, in whose case, the link given should give you enough ideas.

Comment: Thank you, it sounds like exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hook, or a continuous integration tool, that would trigger different deployment target depending on which branch gets updated.

You would have a central repo, with `beta` and `production` branches. When you want to release to beta, commit it the `beta` branch, and push to the central repo. Then the hook or script, recognizing that the `beta` branch has been updated, takes action and deploy accordingly to the beta server.

Same thing for production commit.